# spring MongoOperation could get record count but could not get the corresponding results to the same Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm recently working with the latest spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE, with spring-core 4.1.6, spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE, spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE.

In my case, I'd written something like this:

```
java.util.List<Tag> records = new java.util.ArrayList<Tag>();
records.count = tagRepos.countTags(query);
if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("[getTags] count -> {}", records.count);
if(records.count > 0){
  records.records = tagRepos.findTags(query); 
  if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) LOG.debug("[getTags] records -> {}", records.records);
}
return records;
```

And the result above prints out:
[getTags] count -> 2
[getTags] records -> []

No matter the Query object contains criteria or not, the results both the same.

I'd searched for the same situation for a long time but with no luck. Any one has encounter the same problem? I could figure out the problem is on the MongoTemplate#find method, but I could not work out what is the problem is by the time. Could any one help me out ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some debug I could figure out the problem is happened on the pagination. I'd set page 1 as the first page, but I found spring-data use index 0 as the first page, causing me always try to fetch the second page contents which is not as my expect. So the code is doing very well, that's a good news.